# Android: mixing audio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm developing an Android app that record voice using mediarecorder and play music using mediaplayer.

My goal is to make possible to mix the two audio's into one file, and because Android do not offer any API for it, I am looking for a reasonable solution.

At moment, at play time I'm using a new mediarecorder with MIC source to capture the audio and save it, but this is very poor !!!

Anyway to mix the audio? including any native solution lix SOX or FFMPEG?

Or, anyway to recorder into file using as source the mediaplayer output instead to use the MIC?

Any suggestion is appreciate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When I faced the same problem I was able to find a solution for mixing the files.
Since mixing of two mp3 file is not possible, you have to first convert it in wave format , then set the header value .after that add the data field. I did this in following way. Hope my code will help you.

class MixFile extends AsyncTask{

```
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog= new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Mixing two wav files");
        dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        short[] audioData1 = null;
        short[] audioData2 = null;

        int n = 0;

        try {
            DataInputStream in1;
```

//              in1 = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Soundrecpluspro/one.wav"));
                in1 = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(path1));
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

```
            try {

                while ((n = in1.read()) != -1) {
                    bos.write(n);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bos.toByteArray());
            bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            ShortBuffer sb = bb.asShortBuffer();
            audioData1 = new short[sb.capacity()];

            for (int i = 0; i < sb.capacity(); i++) {
                audioData1[i] = sb.get(i);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            DataInputStream in1;
            in1 = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(path2));
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            try {

                while ((n = in1.read()) != -1) {
                    bos.write(n);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bos.toByteArray());
            bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            ShortBuffer sb = bb.asShortBuffer();
            audioData2=  new short[sb.capacity()];

            sb.get(audioData2);


            System.out.println();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // find the max:



        float max = 0;

        Log.d("File audio lenght 1 ", ""+audioData1.length);
        Log.d("File audio lenght 2 ", ""+audioData2.length);

        System.out.println("MainActivity.MixFile.doInBackground() 1"+audioData1.length);
        System.out.println("MainActivity.MixFile.doInBackground() 2"+audioData2.length);

        if(audioData1.length > audioData2.length){

        for (int i = 22; i < audioData2.length; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(audioData1[i] + audioData2[i]) > max)
                max = Math.abs(audioData1[i] + audioData2[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("" + (Short.MAX_VALUE - max));
        int a, b, c;
        // now find the result, with scaling:
        for (int i = 22; i < audioData2.length; i++) {
            a = audioData1[i];
            b = audioData2[i];

            c = Math.round(Short.MAX_VALUE * (audioData1[i] + audioData2[i])
                    / max);

            if (c > Short.MAX_VALUE)
                c = Short.MAX_VALUE;
            if (c < Short.MIN_VALUE)
                c = Short.MIN_VALUE;


            audioData1[i] = (short) c; 

        }

        // to turn shorts back to bytes.
        byte[] end = new byte[audioData1.length * 2];
        ByteBuffer.wrap(end).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(audioData1);

        try {
            OutputStream out  = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/assets/mixer12.wav");
            for (int i = 0; i < end.length; i++) {
                out.write(end[i]);
                out.flush();
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }else{

            System.out.println("MainActivity.MixFile.doInBackground() smaller one");
            for (int i = 22; i < audioData1.length; i++) {
                if (Math.abs(audioData2[i] + audioData1[i]) > max)
                    max = Math.abs(audioData2[i] + audioData1[i]);
            }

            System.out.println("" + (Short.MAX_VALUE - max));
            int a, b, c;
            // now find the result, with scaling:
            for (int i = 22; i < audioData1.length; i++) {
                a = audioData2[i];
                b = audioData1[i];

                c = Math.round(Short.MAX_VALUE * (audioData2[i] + audioData1[i])
                        / max);

                if (c > Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    c = Short.MAX_VALUE;
                if (c < Short.MIN_VALUE)
                    c = Short.MIN_VALUE;


                audioData2[i] = (short) c; 

            }

            // to turn shorts back to bytes.
            byte[] end = new byte[audioData2.length * 2];
            ByteBuffer.wrap(end).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(audioData2);

            try {
                OutputStream out  = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Assets/mixer1.wav");
                for (int i = 0; i < end.length; i++) {
                    out.write(end[i]);
                    out.flush();
                }
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
        return null;
    }
```

and in activity i called it as below

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  new MixFile().execute();

  }
```

here path1 and path2 is the path of  wav file that you want to mix